# log4j log file not getting updated

Tags: java, log4j

I am using a apache's log4j for logging errors in my application. When I start the tomcat server, the log info information is written into the log file as expected (Also the log info is written into the log file when I stop the tomcat server). But when I start using the application, I log information I am expecting to be written through the app is not written into the log file. For e.g. I am giving inputs that will give exception, but the log.error(e,e) isn't getting written in the log file.

this is how i am using the Logger
`static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

`log.info("my message" );`
`log.error(e,e);`
Please help

EDIT: Adding log4j.properties file contents

`log4j.rootLogger =INFO, FILE, stdout
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p\t\t%c{1} :%L - %m%n`

Comment: Can you share your log4j configuration as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not configured your logger. Please find `log4j.xml` or `logging.properties` typically located under `TOMCAT_HOME/conf`. Edit them to include your application's package.

This will help you to write your application level log messages to log file of your server (tomcat).

Better way is to manage your own logging configuration and files. Create `log4j.xml` file and put it under `WEB-INF/classes` into your application. You can find a lot of examples and tutorials that will help you to write your `log4j.xml`. For example this one: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html